# Grunt: Fatal Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to start Grunt on Windows, but getting an error: `Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT`. I've installed Git and NodeJS, and then ran the following:

```
npm install -g bower grunt-cli cordova
npm install
bower install
grunt build
grunt serve
```

I then tried:

- clearing the cache from npm (`npm cache clean`)
- reinstalled npm
- adding `C:\Windows\Systems32\;` to the path variable.

But I can't get it to work.

Comment: When exactly do you get the error I mean after which command? Can you also show entire error?

Comment: I got the error when I ran the command "grunt build". The error is: `(...) Running "newer:copy:tmp" <newer> task No newer files to process. Running "ionic:build:" <ionic> task Fatal error:spawn cmd ENOENT Execution Time (...)`

Comment: Possible reason could be that grunt can't find ionic executable file. Can you verify ionic is properly installed by running `ionic -v` in command line

Comment: i wrote `ionic -v` and got that ionic was not found, so i installed ionic with `npm install -g ionic`.The version is now 1.7.14. Then I tried grunt build again, but the error was the same like before

Comment: Is the gruntfile from some project you downloaded from internet? If so where? Or can you post here the build part of gruntfile? From a quick search on google it's obvious a lot of people having problem with child_process.spawn call which results in the error you mentioned.

Comment: the files are greated by yeoman and it was the ionic generator.

Comment: The problem is solved. I reinstalled my laptop and  updated to Windows 10. Now grunt serve works :)